# How to launch application on BB10 dev alpha device

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

Hi I am new to blackberry and I have developed an app for BB10. I have tested it on simulator it is working fine.But when I try to launch the app on BB10 dev alpha device it gives an error "Unable to lauch app due to error 22".
The steps that I have used :

First I have created Developer Certificate using :

```
blackberry-signer -register -csjpin <csj pin> -storepass <KeystorePassword> <client-RDK-xxxxxx.csj file><client-PBDT-xxxxx.csj file>
```

Second I have created a Debug token using :

```
blackberry-debugtokenrequest -storepass <KeystorePassword> -devicepin <device PIN> <debug_token_file_name.bar>
```

Then I installed the debug token in the dev alpha device using :

```
blackberry-deploy -installDebugToken <path to debug token> -device <IP address of device> -password <device password>
```

Then i have compiled the application using :

```
bbwp [drive:][path]archive -d [-o dir]
```

Then I have Deployed the application using the following syntax:

```
blackberry-deploy -installApp -password <device password> -device <IP address of device> -package <BAR file path>
```

The application is installed in the device correctly but when I click on the application icon I got error 22.

Please help me so that i can rup app on device.

------*-------*------*-------*------*-------*------*-------*------*-------*------*-------*

When I tried to launch the app through ripple then also i got the same error.
Here is what i see on the cmd prompt.

```
2013-02-28 11:13:31 GET /ripple/build_status/6362 200
Info: Sending request: Install and Launch


Info: Action: Install and Launch

Info: File size: 411108

Info: Installing App.testDev_App___dbc068a4...
Info: Processing 411108 bytes

Info: Progress 96%...

Info: Progress 100%...

actual_dname::App.testDev_App___dbc068a4
actual_id::testDev_App___dbc068a4
actual_version::2.0.0.0
result::success
Info: Launching App.testDev_App___dbc068a4...

Error: Error loading application package: Invalid argument
```

Please help so that I can proceed.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="2.0.0.0" id="someId">

  <author href="https://www.example.com/"
          rim:copyright="Copyright 1998-2012 My Corp">quepp</author>

  <name>appName</name>

  <description>
    description
  </description>

  <!--<icon src="icon"/>-->

  <content src="index.html"/>

  <feature id="blackberry.app">
    <param name="backgroundColor" value="FFFFFF" />
  </feature>

  <feature id="blackberry.app">
    <param name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  </feature>

  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.identity" />

 <access uri="*" subdomains="true" />

  <license href="" />

  <rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
  </rim:permissions>

</widget>
```

Comment: Did you turn on development mode on the device?

Comment: Yes i did...Because without that it is not possible to install the app on device.

Comment: Can you post your config.xml file? And can you verify that the name you put in your Author tag matches what you used for your signing keys?

Comment: I have updated my question with config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Does you app need to access some restricted resources, like camera or files ?

In this case you need to add the relevant permissions in your config.xml.

Comment: No, My app doesn,t needs to access camera

Answer (score 0):

I use signing keys so just use them.
(COMMAND LINE PARAMETERS CAN CHANGE)
    cd C:\Program Files\Research in Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11

After that, sign the App

```
bbwp FOLDER_APP -g PASS_KEY --buildId NUMBER -o OPUTPUT FOLDER -d
```

Where:

```
-d => debug
FOLDER APP => where you have your webworks app
PASS_KEY => the password to sign an app(I supose you can ignore this parameter)
```

After that, go to

```
cd dependencies\tools\bin
```

And deploy the app:

```
blackberry-deploy -installApp -password PASS_DEVICE -device IP -package BAR FILE
```

where:

```
password => the password of your device fixed AFTER activating the development mode.
IP => the IP of your device(I deploy via WIFI).
BAR FILE => path to your previously generated bar file.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Pablo Flores. But now i am able to launch my application.I have updated the OS of the device .

Comment: Can you help me figured out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748360/blackberry-10-webworks-sdk-command-line-generate-build-with-package-and-signing

Comment: Answered. If you need more help with that issue, You can ask me :P