# Blackberry 10 Webworks SDK command line generate build with package and signing

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

So I already was able to build the .bar file, but now I want to build the .bar file to be sent to the store with the package and signing.

So far I've tried this.

```
bbwp C:\xampp\htdocs\maddash\packaged\maddash.zip -g (password) -b 1.0.0 -o C:\xampp\htdocs\maddash\packaged\
```

and my error is..
**failed to find signing key file**

Comment: Any news on this? I'm trying to use `bbwp` on Windows 10 and I get the same error. It works on Windows 7. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your keys from RIM and put them in the default location (%HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Research In Motion for Windows)

Did you update your SDK? Then check your keys in bbwp\bin and rename sigtool to author and move your file to the default location.

If not sufficient, try installing the native IDE and use the UI for managing the keys in the preferences

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with not using a real author.p12 file.  I'm not sure how to generate one, and where it needs to be in the .zip file or.. directory structure.

Comment: In that case, install the Momentics IDE for native dev. It will be like a tank to kill a fly but it will work easily

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion about this problem.

First. If you have your signing key, great for you, because BB changed the system of signing apps. (Now they use BBtokenID, related with your BBID and, in this moment, the webworks framework is the only one that doesn't support this tokens) (Come on, Hip, Hip, Hurrah! :P).

According to your command, one comment

```
bbwp C:\xampp\htdocs\maddash\packaged\maddash.zip -g (password) -b 1.0.0 -o C:\xampp\htdocs\maddash\packaged\
```

In the first paramenter yoy must add the FOLDER of your source code, not your zipped code.

If you have your keys where it corresponds, it will generate a bar file signed.

NOW, you must package it in a zip file. If you need more help with that, tell me :)

Comment: How long should this take it appears to be taking a while and allocating a lot of memory?

Comment: Still getting an error "cannot sign application" failed to find signing key file: author.p12

Comment: What kind of keys do you have? the old one, or the bbtokenid?